# Decomposing the prediction of a sum of Gaussian Processes into predictions from each Gaussian Process

Tags: regression, predictive-models, gaussian-process, sum

Suppose the functions $f_1\sim\mathcal{GP}(m_1,K_1)$ and $f_2\sim\mathcal{GP}(m_2,K_2)$ are drawn from independent Gaussian Processes, and let
$$f=f_1+f_2.$$

Then
$$f\sim\mathcal{GP}(m,K)$$
where $m=m_1+m_2$ and $K=K_1+K_2$.

In Gaussian Process regression, the predictive distribution for test inputs $X^{\star}$ becomes
$$\mathbf{f}^{\star}|X^\star\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{m}^\star+\mathbf{K}^{\star\top}\mathbf{K}^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{m}), \mathbf{K}^{\star\star}-\mathbf{K}^{\star\top}\mathbf{K}^{-1}\mathbf{K}^\star)$$

where the symbols are now vectors/matrices evaluated at the training or test points (see Rasmussen's book for an explanation of the notation).

---

**My question:**

I want to ask if it possible to decompose the prediction into the form
$$\text{prediction}=(\text{prediction from first GP})+(\text{prediction from second GP}).$$

According to this [website](https://tinygp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/mixture.html), it should be possible to do so, and the prediction due to the first GP becomes
$$\mathbf{K}_1(\mathbf{K}_1+\mathbf{K}_2)^{-1}\mathbf{y}$$

Is there a proof of this result? Any reference would be good too.